# sql server select from case db

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 db on one server.
I need to write procedure that does select basing on @db variable.

I know 2 possibilities for this:

1. I declare `@SQL nvarchar(max)` and generating my query in plain text. Then i do `exec @SQL`.
   Bad variant imho.
2. I do 2 similar queries and use if @db='' 1st query else 2nd query. Another bad variant because it is code duplicate.

Question is - is there any way to do like this or similar: select * from @db.dbo.table?

Comment: You might want to look at synonyms, but I don't know if you can create one mid-batch. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx

Comment: Table names, including database, can not be specified with a variable without the use of dynamic SQL.  The only other alternative is to prompt the user for the value, and generate a script with the value hardcoded based on user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "exec @SQL" isn't evil.  If it gets the job done and you're not exposing yourself to any security risks then it may be the best way to go.  Another option would be to consider using a real programming language like c# (or whatever your preference is) since they are better equipped to handle these sort of dynamic requirements.

Comment: I know that it isn`t evil, but it hard to test.